# C# TCP Server duplicated message

Tags: c#, server, tcp

I'm developing a TCP Server app (windows forms) and getting there, but it sends duplicated message and I'm not sure why.

This is what I've done:

```
    private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Client client = (Client)result.AsyncState;
        
        try
        {
                int received = client.socket.EndReceive(result);
                string dataReceived = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    serverLog.Add(dataReceived);
                    listBoxStatus.Items.Add(dataReceived);
                    client.history.Add(dataReceived);
                }));

                SentToOthers(client, dataReceived);
            
                // Start a new async receive on the client to receive more data.
                client.socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, OnDataReceived, client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                serverLog.Add("Error: receiving message from " + client.name);
                listBoxStatus.Items.Add(serverLog.Last<string>());
                client.history.Add("Error: sending message to server");
            }));
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private void SentToOthers(Client origin, string s)
    {
        foreach (Client c in clientsList)
        {
            if (c.socket != origin.socket)
            {
                byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
                c.socket.Send(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for my 1st question!

Comment: From what you show here the most likely explanation is that you have the same client in `clientsList` more than once.

Comment: You're right!  ...what a rookie mistake!  I thought of everything but this one because it is too simple!  Thanks!